# Isolate cause of Typescript max recursion error with getAwaitedTypeWorker => getAwaitedType => mapType

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

We have a large Typescript codebase using Typescript 4.4.2 in VS Code and with certain larger TSX files we are seeing the Typescript hints and types freeze regularly.

Under the VS Code `Output => Log (Extension Host)` this is the error we are seeing:

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at getPromisedTypeOfPromise (/my/repo/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsserver.js:77328:42)
    at getAwaitedTypeWorker (/my/repo/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsserver.js:77418:32)
    at mapType (/my/repo/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsserver.js:66541:97)
    at getAwaitedType (/my/repo/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsserver.js:77411:17)
    at getAwaitedTypeWorker (/my/repo/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsserver.js:77462:35)
    at mapType (/my/repo/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsserver.js:66541:97)
    at getAwaitedType (/my/repo/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsserver.js:77411:17)
    at getAwaitedTypeWorker (/my/repo/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsserver.js:77462:35)
...
    at getAwaitedType (/my/repo/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsserver.js:77411:17)
    at Function.create (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/typescript-language-features/dist/extension.js:1:460421)
    at dispatchResponse (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/typescript-language-features/dist/extension.js:1:454257)
    at dispatchMessage (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/typescript-language-features/dist/extension.js:1:453114)
    at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/typescript-language-features/dist/extension.js:1:452599
    at l.fire (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:66:1712)
    at m.onLengthData (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/typescript-language-features/dist/extension.js:1:463350)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/typescript-language-features/dist/extension.js:1:462997)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:309:12)
    at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:284:9)
```

We have a thousands of references to `Promise`, `await` and `async` throughout the codebase and there's no obvious culprit in the TSX file in question.  Curiously the affected files have no direct references to `Promise`, `await`, or `async`, though they certainly include types that do. It's not apparent how to isolate the problematic case.

Is there any way to help find out what the TS language server is circularly referencing here?

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, did you end up finding a way to debug this?

Comment: @JH-I'm afraid not — please post if you do!